# MAX on multiple offset arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, max, offset

I have the following data in Excel. This is a simplified version of what I have, take note that the figures do not share a row or a column with the name.

```
Martin              
        145 171 130
Dave                
        157 190 201
Darren              
        122 199 177
Mark                
        197 183 202
Dan                 
        186 139 168
Martin              
        185 204 156
Dave                
        197 172 158
Darren              
        231 228 217
Mark                
        173 192 205
Dan                 
        214 166 172
```

What I would like is a list of distinct names, with the maximum figure next to it.

I've tried something like this: `{=MAX(IF(B1:B50=I2,OFFSET(INDEX(B1:B50,MATCH(I2,B1:B50,0)),1,1,3,3)))}` but doesn't work.

I am aware if the figures are on the same row as the name, I can use `{=MAX(IF(B:B=I2,C:E))}`, but I'm trying to prevent moving the figures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=max(offset($B$1:$D$1,match(I2,$A1:$A1:$A50,0)))
```

Changes from yours

- Doesn't need to be an array formula
- The array size is set in the first part of the offset function
- Index is not needed as you are not trying to return a certain cell you are just looking for an offset number which match provides

Note that offset is a volatile function which can slow down the sheet if its large (can force all cells to update every small change), but I can't think of a better solution off the top of my head.

With duplicate names this would should work, just build the offset into the array if function

```
={MAX(IF($A$1:$A$50=I2,$B$2:$D$51,""))}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this only search the first instance of the name though? There will be multiple lines with Martin in, with values underneath.

Comment: Added another formula that should work with duplicate names